# How to insert some user defined custom parameter directly to MANIFEST dynamically?

Tags: java, maven

I'm using maven to build. We have plenty of different Java API that we have to package as WAR and have to release to the different clients. Our requirement is to put different parameters and values inside `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` based on different artifacts. Can anyone please guide me how to inject different user define values during build directly inside `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`?

Comment: `during build at runtime`

???

Comment: Corrected it. I need to modify manifest with custom parameters during build. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POM file should have entries like below e.g **param1,param1,param1** and value that you want are **value1,value2,value2** respectively

```
<plugins>
      <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.1.1</version>
       <configuration>
           <archive>
               <manifestEntries>
                   <version>${project.version}</version>
                   <param1>${param1}</param1>
                   <param2>${param2}</param2>
                   <param3>${param3}</param3>
               </manifestEntries>
           </archive>
       </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

After that You can insert different parameters from terminal during maven build like

> mvn clean install -Dparam1=value1 -Dparam2=value2 -Dparam3=value2

Your MANIFEST.MF should have values like below.

```
Manifest-Version: *****
Archiver-Version: ******
Created-By: Apache Maven
param1: value1
param2: value2
param3: value2
version: ********
```

Comment: Thanks, I want different key value to be inserted dynamically in Manifest during build. It works!